# AWS auroradb automatically close connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, jdbc, serverless, aws-serverless, amazon-aurora

I am accessing `auroradb` service from my `java` `lambda` code. Here I set my lambda concurrency as 1. 
Since creating/closing database connection is an expensive process, I have created the `mysql` connection and made it static. So it will reuse the same connection every time. I haven't added the code to close the connection.

Will it cause any problems?

Will it automatically close after some days?

Comment: Did you need anything else answered as part of this post?

Answer (score 0):

Most certainly yes! When your lambda "cools" down, your connection to the database will be broken. The next time you invoke your lambda, it goes through a cold start, and your lambda code should initialize the connection again. This is a standard issue with working with persisted connections from serverless infrastructure.

What you need to use is something like a REST API for your data apis, and that's something Aurora Serverless supports as beta.

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/11/aurora-serverless-data-api-beta/

Each request is a independent HTTP request, and you don't end up managing you persisted connections.